# Numerically check the gradient is a linear operator

Tags: python, pytorch

Given the following two snippets of code, the first one is designed to iterate over each MNIST sample individually, calculate the loss and find the individual gradients. At the end, all the individual gradients are added and divided by the length of the training dataset to calculate the full gradient (batch). In the second snippet of code, the entire dataset is used as a mini-batch, resulting in a batch gradient calculation. Mathematically, both methods should provide the same result. However, when checking the norm square of the first and second gradients, they are very different. Why does the first method differ from the second method?

**Code snippet 1:**

```
import torch
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch import nn

# Download MNIST dataset
train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor(), download=True)

# Define LeNet-300-100-10 model
class LeNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = torch.nn.Linear(28 * 28, 300)
        self.fc2 = torch.nn.Linear(300, 100)
        self.fc3 = torch.nn.Linear(100, 10)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Initialize model with seed 0
torch.manual_seed(0)
model = LeNet()

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
model.to(device)

# Initialize grad_sum
grad_sum = [torch.zeros_like(param) for param in model.parameters()]

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_dataset):
    # Forward pass
    labels = torch.tensor(labels)
    images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
    outputs = model(images)
    # Calculate loss
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels.unsqueeze(0))   
    # Zero out gradient
    model.zero_grad()
    # Backward pass for one image
    loss.backward()
    # Add gradient to grad_sum
    for i, param in enumerate(model.parameters()):
        grad_sum[i] += param.grad

grad = [grad_sum[i] / len(train_dataset) for i in range(len(grad_sum))]

norm_sq = 0
for p_grad in grad:
      norm_sq += torch.norm(p_grad) ** 2

print(norm_sq)
```

**Code snippet 2:**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
from torchvision.transforms import ToTensor

# Define LeNet-300-100-10 model
class LeNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28 * 28, 300)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(300, 100)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(100, 10)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Load MNIST dataset
train_dataset = MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=ToTensor())

# Create DataLoader for training dataset
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=len(train_dataset), shuffle=True)

# Move data to device (GPU if available)
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

torch.manual_seed(0)
# Create model instance
model = LeNet().to(device)

# Define loss function and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Forward pass
for images, labels in train_loader:

    images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
    
    # Calculate loss
    outputs = model(images)
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

    # Zero out gradients
    model.zero_grad()
    
    # Backward pass
    loss.backward()

for param in model.parameters():
    norm_sq += torch.norm(param.grad) ** 2

print(norm_sq)
```

Comment: I get very similar results from the two examples. First: `tensor(0.0255)` Second: `tensor(0.0262)` Do you get something else? The second one doesn't seem to be deterministic though. Not sure why.

Comment: To add to the comment of @NickODell, I think you need to add `torch.cuda.manual_seed(0)`,  `torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True`, 
and `torch.backends.cudnn.benchmark = False` to set the seeds when using GPU, but in this case I get different results for each shuffle from the dataloader from the second snippet (some are similar some aren't).

Comment: @Nick ODell: The should be exactly the same. Did you check the first 10 elements of the the gradient for two code snippets?

Comment: @Lev_Descartski: In the second snippet there is no shuffling. It takes the whole data and does it.

Comment: I added `torch.manual_seed(0)` to the second one. I get `0.025466` and `0.026920`. It is NOT numerical error because using ```for param in model.parameters():
    print(torch.nonzero(param.grad))
    break``` nonzero ones for the first code snippet ARE ```[  2, 184],
        [  2, 185],
        [  2, 186],
        ``` not the same as ```[  0,  12],
        [  0,  13],
        [  0,  33],
       ```

Comment: You also have one extra softmax used in the second snippet, which is not the case in the first snippet's LeNet definition.

Comment: @Lev_Descartski: You are right. I removed it, but weirdly it did not change the nonzero indices.